# How to create a cocoa app windows like tweetie

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I'm new to cocoa app dev, and I'm searching a solution to create a windows like the tweetie main windows with a left tool bar and a panel that point to the selected icon.

like this screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvxWu.jpg

could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that a lot of the Tweetie UI is implemented using custom controls. You'll want to look into subclassing NSView and how to handle drawing and mouse events. There's nothing built into the Cocoa framework for this.

The [NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) documentation has info on [view programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978), [drawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290), and [event handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i). If you're new to Cocoa, you may want to start off with something built in, though, as this will be a lot of work (and requires a pretty good understanding of how the framework works).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried another solution by adding a NSimageView with a small arrow. It work (but not on the Ib preview). the difficult part with this solution it's to resize two component without space between. But It easier (for a newbie) than creating custom control